# Scrolling Widget inside a Constant size Container flutter web

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

Hi all fellow developers,

I am developing a responsive web page in flutter using the flutter web SDK, but i am stuck at one part of the page where i have a Row inside row I have 2 Containers among which i want the 1st Container to be Scrollable and the Second container to be of constant size(Non scrollable) just like whatsapp web ui where contact list keeps scrolling but the chat side and the rest of the page doesn't.

please Help me,
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work You need a fixed sized container and make sure a Scroll able widget should be inside it. Now size can be made responsive by using Media Query Parameters and below code you only need to adjust space and sizing and it would work.

```
Row(
              //Your parent Row
              children: [
                Container(
                  //static non scrollable container
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      //Children you want to add 
                      //this wont be scrollable 
                      //It is also preferred that you give this some height or width too
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  //Scrollable container
                  //Please adjust height and width yourself 
                  //You can use media query parameters to make it responsive
                  width: 200,
                  height: 500,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    //You can also change the scroll direction
                    child: Column(
                      //Add children you want to be in
                      //Scrollable column
                      
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: accept the answer if it is helpful so others can know it will benefit them.